# CookieManger returns only one cookie (Android)

Tags: android-cookiemanager

So I have a webView that loads mobile site... By default site sets first cookie: `PHPSESSID...` After login, I set UID cookie as well... But when I output cookie string, only first cookie is in the string... What am I missing?

here is the code:

```
    CookieManager cManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

    cManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

    String cs = cManager.getCookie("http://dev.healthcasts.com/home");

    Log.i("APPOUT", "ID/////////////////////: " + cs);
```

this what I get in the output:

> ID/////////////////////: PHPSESSID=a2bf924cd04ce9ca3aa6fa92fef12b20

but in Chrome browser it shows 2 cookies set after login... So it should be:

PHPSESSID=a2bf924cd04ce9ca3aa6fa92fef12b20;UID=123456

basically CookieManager ignores second cookie for some reason...

Same site when it's running on iOS also outputs 2 cookies like it should. What am I missing?